# I want to identify the public ip of the terraform execution environment and add it to the security group

Tags: terraform

I want to identify the public IP of the terraform execution environment
and add it to aws security group inbound to prevent access from other environments.

Currently, I am manually editing the values in the variables.tf file.

variables.tf

```
variable public_ip_address {
  default     = "xx"
}
```

I would like to execute the "curl ifconfig.co" command on the local host and automatically set the security group based on the result

Is there a way to do such things?

I could do it by putting the result of local-exec in some variable
but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16154#issuecomment-338286154

Answer (score 118, accepted):

There's an easier way to do that without any scripts. The trick is having a website such as `icanhazip.com` which retrieve your IP, so set it in your terraform file as `data`:

```
data "http" "myip" {
  url = "https://ipv4.icanhazip.com"
}
```

And whenever you want to place your IP just use `data.http.myip.body`, example:

```
ingress {
  from_port = 5432
  to_port = 5432
  protocol = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["${chomp(data.http.myip.response_body)}/32"]
}
```

- Note I used terraform `chomp()` method to remove any trailing space or new line which comes with body.
- You can use your ipv6 with http://ipv6.icanhazip.com. Take care by just using http://icanhazip.com because it can retrieve ipv4 or ipv6

Comment: How would you update the existing security group with the new value? What if the in the use case every one want to use there own IP in same security group

Comment: @Fo. Unfortunately, Amazon returns `200 OK`, but not a `text/*` or `application/json` Content-Type header, which is required by terraform's http data source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/http/data_source.html

Comment: @kevlened This could do it https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html

Comment: If you're using this to connect to a db instance, don't forget to make the db instance accessible! https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#publicly_accessible

Comment: I would add a security warning. You should not trust the remote IP service... You ought to check that the resulting IP belongs to an authorized list/range of IPs.

Comment: please use HTTPS here in the URL. With HTTP the IP can be modified by an attacker.

Comment: Indeed, https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/ is the safer option here.

Answer (score 21):

In Terraform 0.12 and greater you can use native jsondecode and jsonencode to get better reliability and long term reproducibility rather than relying on string manipulation. For reference, this implementation was tested on Terraform 0.12.16.

An example implementation for grabbing your public ip address using the newer Terraform methods currently available is below. Output block is added to provide visual verification that it is working as intended.

```
data "http" "my_public_ip" {
  url = "https://ifconfig.co/json"
  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/json"
  }
}

locals {
  ifconfig_co_json = jsondecode(data.http.my_public_ip.body)
}

output "my_ip_addr" {
  value = local.ifconfig_co_json.ip
}
```

If you want to utilize this in a network ingress rule, you can do the following (icmp utilized for testability in the example, without unnecessarily opening up ports in case this is blindly copy and pasted) :

```
ingress {
  from_port = 0
  to_port = 0
  protocol = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["${local.ifconfig_co_json.ip}/32"]
}
```

Please note that the service referenced is rate limited to ~1 request per min, so you might end up wanting to host this yourself if your needs exceed this; or if you need more guaranteed availability. The echoip service is containerized so can be hosted nearly anywhere.

https://github.com/mpolden/echoip

Comment: this returns ipv6 how do I pass the -4 flag to get v4?

Comment: actually the above might not work if there is a newline character at the end of the inferred value from that IP website

Answer (score 9):

Based on earlier answers this is a much shorter approach:

```
data "http" "ip" {
  url = "https://ifconfig.me/ip"
}

output "ip" {
  value = data.http.ip.response_body
}
```

Comment: url is https://ifconfig.me/ip however

Comment: @DOMZE, does not matter, try "curl ifconfig.me" on the cli yourself :)

Comment: interesting, they probably detect the user agent and act accordingly. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: True, I was thinking the exact same thing :) When I show this to sysadmins, they never understand and think I am typing "ipconfig".

Comment: ".body" is now deprecated, it should be ".response_body"
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http#response_body
I also recommend keeping "/ip" as you don't know if the website will change the behaviour of user agent detection. At least with "/ip", you are sure that the body will be just the ip

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant solution I could come up with is to use the "external data source" provider. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html

This was written for these kind of purposes where people were combining local-exec, null-resource and vars to inject something locally.

Anyway, I'm sure you can do this without writing a small script. The thing is the "external data source" expects to read JSON. So in my example I just built a JSON string in a program and then call that program. I'm sure this could be done in a one liner using echo or jq...

Here is my main.tf file:

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = ["sh", "test.sh" ]
}

output "commandout" {
  value = "${data.external.example.result}"
}
```

Here is my shell script (test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo {\"ip\":\""`hostname -I`"\"}
```

Technically once you have this situation you can use:

```
${data.external.example.result}
```

As your var input.

Here is my working example with terraform output.

```
data.external.example: Refreshing state...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

commandout = {
  ip = 10.0.2.15
}
```

Note that `hostname -I` is ok if you only have one NIC :) Otherwise use an alternative command or cut the output for your desired results.

Comment: awesome!! I have a question about main.tf
Is main.tf executed the first time in terraform? could it use anywhere settings defined in main.tf?

Comment: Terraform loads *.tf in workspace, your values need to be available in present workspace or imported via remote data.

Comment: @AnshuPrateek Can you see my new question? I have not solved the fundamental problem yet.   link is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311916/how-to-put-in-varable-tf-to-run-script-with-data-external-in-terraform

Comment: `hostname -I` shows all ip addresses of the NICs but this only shows you the local IP address on any private network unless you aren't NAT'ed in anyway. If you're NAT'ed it's unlikely your system knows the external, public IP at all so you'd need to fetch it from the outside world. Thankfully there are services for this so you'd be better off running something like `curl ifconfig.co` which will return the IP address you connected to it from.

Answer (score 0):

```
data "http" "myip" {
  url = "http://ipv4.icanhazip.com"
}

  ingress {
    description = "ssh from my ip"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${chomp(data.http.myip.response_body)}/32"]
  }
```

Here is what works for me.