# Is there a way to add client IP in Azure database for mysql using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-database-mysql

I have created Azure database for mysql using terraform and have enabled access to azure services in it using terraform, so is there a way to add client IP also in it through terraform only?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`azurerm_mysql_firewall_rule`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mysql_firewall_rule) or `azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule` if that is what you are using

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "api-rg-pro"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_server" "example" {
  # ...
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_firewall_rule" "example" {
  name                = "office"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.example.name
  start_ip_address    = "40.112.8.12"
  end_ip_address      = "40.112.8.12"
}
```

Comment: it adds a specific ip, but i want to add the client ip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763287/i-want-to-identify-the-public-ip-of-the-terraform-execution-environment-and-add

Comment: not public ip, i want to add the client ip

Comment: i tried this by adding firewall resource twice, one for public ip and one for client ip, so it worked fine, which resolves my requirement, Thanks

Comment: @abhsihek Thank you for following up. If you feel your question was resolved, please consider marking the answer as "accepted". This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.