# Terraform Cloud not able to create container in storage account that is behind firewall

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage-account, terraform-cloud

Facing "Unauthorized error (403)" while creating container in storage account that is behind firewall.

As per solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53782560), I confirm that Terraform cloud Public IP is getting whitelisted under Networking --> Firewall of storage account. Service Principal of Terraform cloud is having Contributor as well as Storage Blob Data Owner permissions under Access Control (IAM). However, I am still facing the "Unauthorized error (403)" during the creation of Container. Am I missing something from configuration perspective ?

ERROR message: containers.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

[Terraform Cloud Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZZNx.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the error as text if possible.

Comment: @MarkoE Added the error details.

Answer (score 1):

*I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results*

*I have the below script to create the storage account and the storage container*

*I have taken the example script from this [URL](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account)*

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources_new"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "virtnetname123"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "subnetname123"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["XXXXX"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql", "Microsoft.Storage"]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                = "storageaccountname123aks"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    ip_rules                   = ["XXXX"]
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id]
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "vhds123"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

*When I run the script I got the same error as shown below*

[image]

*To resolve this error I have modified the settings in the azure portal like below*

*Go-To Portal => storage-account => networking => add the client IP address under the firewall check the below steps to added on the screenshot and saved the modifications.*

[image]

*I have the contributor role and data owner permissions under the access control*

[image]

*Again I ran the terraform script now I am able to see the expected output*

```
terraform plan
```

[image]

```
terraform apply
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @komali-annem. From your solution, it seems that you've run the `terrafom apply` command from your local machine and which is why it worked. Can you please try the same from Terraform Cloud ?

Comment: I was totally looking into terraform permissions but issue was on storage networking rules. You saved my hours of debugging. Thank you @komali-annem